# Django simple captcha

Tags: python, django

Решил использовать в проекте самую простую капчу [django-simple-captcha](http://code.google.com/p/django-simple-captcha/) и столкнулся с тем, что не random в коде почему-то выдает всегда одни и теже значения, что на локалке, что на хосте. Причем для генерации перепробовал все возможные способы.

```
def random_char_challenge():
    chars,ret = list(u'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), u''
    random.shuffle(chars)
    for i in range(settings.CAPTCHA_LENGTH):
        ret += random.choice(chars)
        random.shuffle(chars)
    return ret.upper(),ret

def myrandom_char_challenge():
    random.shuffle(settings.my_alphabet)
    ret = u''
    for ch in random.sample(settings.my_alphabet,settings.CAPTCHA_LENGTH):   
        ret += ch 
    return ret.upper(),ret
```

settings.my_alphabet задал в settings, чтобы всегда были перемешаные значения. помогло но не сильно....

может в самом использовании капчи ошибка?

исользую так

```
class FlatForm(forms.ModelForm):
captcha = CaptchaField()
class Meta:
    model = Flats
    exclude = ('user', 'views', 'added', 'unlimited',
        'add1', 'objtype','key')
```

вот результат на [сайте](http://www.moskva-nedvigimost.ru/addobject/flat/)
я конечно могу переписать код капчи, и чтобы не создании объекта в базе,он проверялся на уникальность, но с рандом как-то странно выходит.
это сеттинги проекта

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'captcha',
    )
   #urls.py
url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
```

это сеттинги капчи
    import os
    from django.conf import settings

```
CAPTCHA_FONT_PATH = getattr(settings,'CAPTCHA_FONT_PATH', os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'fonts/Vera.ttf'))) 
CAPTCHA_FONT_SIZE = getattr(settings,'CAPTCHA_FONT_SIZE', 24)
CAPTCHA_LETTER_ROTATION = getattr(settings, 'CAPTCHA_LETTER_ROTATION', (-20,20))
CAPTCHA_BACKGROUND_COLOR = getattr(settings,'CAPTCHA_BACKGROUND_COLOR', '#ffffff')
CAPTCHA_FOREGROUND_COLOR= getattr(settings,'CAPTCHA_FOREGROUND_COLOR', '#ae0033')
CAPTCHA_CHALLENGE_FUNCT = getattr(settings,'CAPTCHA_CHALLENGE_FUNCT','captcha.helpers.myrandom_char_challenge')
CAPTCHA_NOISE_FUNCTIONS = getattr(settings,'CAPTCHA_NOISE_FUNCTIONS', ('captcha.helpers.noise_arcs','captcha.helpers.noise_dots',))
CAPTCHA_FILTER_FUNCTIONS = getattr(settings,'CAPTCHA_FILTER_FUNCTIONS',('captcha.helpers.post_smooth',))
CAPTCHA_WORDS_DICTIONARY = getattr(settings,'CAPTCHA_WORDS_DICTIONARY', '/usr/share/dict/words')
CAPTCHA_PUNCTUATION = getattr(settings, 'CAPTCHA_PUNCTUATION', '''_"',.;:-''')
CAPTCHA_FLITE_PATH = getattr(settings,'CAPTCHA_FLITE_PATH',None)
CAPTCHA_TIMEOUT = getattr(settings, 'CAPTCHA_TIMEOUT', 4) # Minutes
CAPTCHA_LENGTH = int(getattr(settings, 'CAPTCHA_LENGTH', 5)) # Chars
CAPTCHA_IMAGE_BEFORE_FIELD = getattr(settings,'CAPTCHA_IMAGE_BEFORE_FIELD', True)
CAPTCHA_DICTIONARY_MIN_LENGTH = getattr(settings,'CAPTCHA_DICTIONARY_MIN_LENGTH', 0)
CAPTCHA_DICTIONARY_MAX_LENGTH = getattr(settings,'CAPTCHA_DICTIONARY_MAX_LENGTH', 99)
if CAPTCHA_IMAGE_BEFORE_FIELD:
    CAPTCHA_OUTPUT_FORMAT = getattr(settings,'CAPTCHA_OUTPUT_FORMAT', u'%(image)s %(hidden_field)s %(text_field)s')
else:
    CAPTCHA_OUTPUT_FORMAT = getattr(settings,'CAPTCHA_OUTPUT_FORMAT', u'%(hidden_field)s %(text_field)s %(image)s')

# Failsafe
if CAPTCHA_DICTIONARY_MIN_LENGTH > CAPTCHA_DICTIONARY_MAX_LENGTH:
    CAPTCHA_DICTIONARY_MIN_LENGTH, CAPTCHA_DICTIONARY_MAX_LENGTH = CAPTCHA_DICTIONARY_MAX_LENGTH, CAPTCHA_DICTIONARY_MIN_LENGTH

def _callable_from_string(string_or_callable):
    if callable(string_or_callable):
        return string_or_callable
    else:
        return getattr(__import__( '.'.join(string_or_callable.split('.')[:-1]), {}, {}, ['']), string_or_callable.split('.')[-1])

def get_challenge():
    return _callable_from_string(CAPTCHA_CHALLENGE_FUNCT)

def noise_functions():
    if CAPTCHA_NOISE_FUNCTIONS:
        return map(_callable_from_string, CAPTCHA_NOISE_FUNCTIONS)
    return list()

def filter_functions():
    if CAPTCHA_FILTER_FUNCTIONS:
        return map(_callable_from_string, CAPTCHA_FILTER_FUNCTIONS)
    return list()

my_alphabet = list(u'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, как подключили в сеттингах.

Comment: Обновил. Вообще странно все это, именно рандом стабильно рандомит одно и тоже число в дебаггере.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте явно указать вашу функцию-обработчик в settings.py:

```
CAPTCHA_CHALLENGE_FUNCT = 'path.to.myrandom_char_challenge'
```

Я использовал точно так же, как и вы - только строил форму не на основе модели, а в пару полей. Может в этом проблема? Хотя сиииильно в этом сомневаюсь.

Comment: да дело точно не сеттингах, я при вывозе генерации уже напрямую функцию прописывал. Есть бредовая мысль, что может дело реально в модели...хотя может ключ как-то кэшируется и мне просто при обновлении страницы приходит тот же самый ключ...только вот кем и как он кэшируется. Убился с этим вопросом нафиг =)

Comment: А, кстати! Вы поля формы выводите через шаблонные теги или вручную забиваете по айдишникам??

Comment: через шаблонные теги...хотя там форма большая может я один какой-нибудь и через id'шник забил =) а думаете разница есть?

Comment: Разница большая, если капчу просто скопипастили - то скопировали и хэши, и значит она будет генерироваться разная, но отображаться одинаковая и валидацию не пройдёт. Сам с таким столкнулся, когда впервые прикручивал эту капчу. Проверьте хэши у капчи в коде страницы. Если хэш постоянно один и тот же и форма валидна - значит у вас проблема с функцией-генератором, в противном случае - копайте в сторону шаблонных тегов, может выводите как-то "криво" ;) Удачи!